# HTML/CSS bottom navigation misplaced

Tags: html, css

I am very new at both HTML and CSS but learning on the way. I have come to a stuck point and I can't seem to work it out. When viewing my webpage I have noticed that when I 'inspect element' the bottomnav div and ul div are both the size of my main div which is basically 0.

This is causing my issues in terms of trying to place a boarder on my bottom navigation.

None of the images are working but here it is
Code: http://jsbin.com/xuluqugovu/edit?html,css,output

Thanks for anyone's help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `overflow:auto` on the `.main` rule (*since its contents are floated, it does not expand to contain them*)

Comment: Thank you for that! That's worked perfectly and learnt something new. Much appreciated.